# BackupAgent not working in Jelly bean. A bug in Jelly bean?

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-backup-service

I am testing the sample code `BackupRestore` from Android SDK 16 (with my own key), but it does not work. The exactly same code works for ICS and GB. When I reinstall the app, I got

```
09-08 23:55:27.159: I/BackupManagerService(149): New app com.example.android.backuprestore never backed up; scheduling
```

When opening the app after reinstall, I got

```
09-08 23:53:48.240: I/PerformBackupTask(149): no backup data written; not calling transport
```

I found this thread on Stackoverflow which said that there might be a bug in JB. Anyone is aware or can confirm there is indeed a bug? Any workaround?

Comment: Just to clarify: I am using emulators for all releases so there is no device variable here.

Comment: The link to the other thread that talks about jelly bean bug. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377313/backupmanager-not-calling-backup-transport

Answer (score 0):

I've been working with this extensively in JB and there are no bugs that I'm aware of.  Most of the backup related AOSP code is untouched from ICS to JB.

Remember that the standard BackupHelpers will not generate backups for unchanged data and BackupManagerService will not call the transport if there is no data to back up.

Comment: And you didn't do anything special for backup manager to work on JB ? We are having troubles with JB as other people reported on the thread mentionned in the question's comments.