# Cordova - Permanent storage even after uninstall

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am developing an app using cordova (currently only releasing on Android) and I am struggling with storage options.

I am currently using Local Storage which seems to work well, however all data/values are wiped if the user uninstalls and reinstalls the app. I was wondering if there is a plugin or some way to permanently store data on Android even if the user uninstalls the app?

The reason I would like this is to allow the user to keep the coins they have earned/purchased if they were to remove the app and then get it back at a later date? I also have an 'ad free' IAP and I am currently storing a value in Local Storage when the user purchases this so don't want the ads to come back if they uninstall/reinstall.

If this is not possible is there an alternative way to recognise if the user has purchased the Ad Free IAP so they will always have no ads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [cordova-plugin-cloud-settings](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-cloud-settings) to persist key/value data between installs / across same-platform devices.

Comment: Thanks a lot, looks like a promising solution. Do you know about often the settings are backed up to the cloud? For example, if someone downloaded the app, played it for 5-10 minutes, uninstalled it and then reinstalled it a few days later would their settings be saved?

Comment: Backups are not that frequent (approx daily) and when certain conditions are met, depending on platform and version: [iCloud (iOS)](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3376384#31527808022), [Auto Backup (Android 6+)](http://androiddoc.qiniudn.com/training/backup/autosyncapi.html), [Backup API (Android <=5)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27751837/777265)

Answer (score 0):

You can save user data online. Check [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/)
Fetch the data from the server when needed.

Or you can also write it on a file and save it on local storage (not a good idea for most of the time)

Answer (score 0):

This is terrible practice. You should always keep server side the amount of earned/purchased items then fetch them as you start the app. It wouldn't be too hard to download and rebuild your app in debug mode then change the local storage.